# Search Chinese Character by Pinyin in search bar

Tags: php, html

I would like to add a search function for the contact. But some of them might be in Chinese words. So i want to search it by pinyin.

For instance, "我" is in the contact. And when i key in "w" or "wo". then 我 will show up in the search bar. Im storing my contact in mysql database and code with php.

Comment: use mysql utf-8 search which is helpful for non English character set